# Is there a common function to translate string to special character?

Tags: javascript, escaping

Assuming that there is an input field named fieldDelimiter, and user input "\\t", i should translate '\\t' to '\t'. ('\\n' to '\n', '\\u0001' to '\u0001' .etc).
Is there a common function to do this?

Comment: Why wouldn't replace work, especially since the input value is going to be a string anyway?

Comment: why not like this: `const newStr = "\\t\\nFoo bar baz \\u0001".replace(/(\\.+)\b/gi, '\$1')`

Comment: @Todd "\\t\\nFoo bar baz \\u0001".replace(/(\\.+)\b/gi, '\$1') === "\\t\\nFoo bar baz \\u0001", not wanted.

Comment: you're right... I was forgetting a crucial detail: I was escaping my own capturing group... lol.

"\\t\\nFoo bar baz \\u0001".replace(/(\\\\.+)\b/gi, '\$1')

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's replace() function to replace `\\` to `\`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

To escape \, you can refer the code below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="inputValue">
        <button onclick="removeSlash()">Remove</button>
        <div id="result">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function removeSlash(){
            var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputValue");
            var result = document.getElementById("result");
            var removed = inputValue.value.replace("\\\\", "\\");
            result.innerHTML = removed;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: \ is escape charactor，\t or \u0001 is a single charactor, I can not just replace \\ to \

Comment: In your case, if inputValue is '\\t', then removed will still be '\\t', you can never translate '\\t' to '\t' by relace method, just replace '\'.

Comment: Do you means you have multiple \\t \\n or something? Because based on the code given, it will convert \\t to \t or \\n to \n

Comment: If in this case, you can refer this answer for replaceall
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-can-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string

Comment: You can try it yourself, then see the result: var value = '\\t'; var removed = value.replace('\\\\', '\\');

Comment: '\t' or '\u0001' is just a single character.

Comment: Or you share source code for us to have better understanding for your condition?